# Power of hypoteses test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am having some problems calculating the power in this exercise.

http://snag.gy/LkulQ.jpg

[image]

This is what i've tried. 
So since i know that $\alpha$ is 0.05. I thereby know that the upper boundary is given by the formula 0.05 has a Z-score = 1.64485

$$ 1.64485 =\frac{\bar{x} - 4}{0.2/\sqrt{50}} \Rightarrow  \bar{x} = 4.04652`$$

Then i calculate $\beta$ by 
$P(z \ge \frac{4.04652 - 4.5}{50/\sqrt{9}}) = 3.76192*10^{-58}$
and thereby the power beeing $1- 3.76192*10^{-58} = 1 $

This should be correct.

Could you also help me with exercise d).. 
So.. I have to choose a sample size which makes the power min 0.9.  this means that $\beta$ has to 0.1. 
So Using the table i see that the necessary Z-score which has a probability of being 0.1, is 1.28155. 
So calculating n would be $Solve[1.28155 = \frac{4.04632 - 4}{0.2/\sqrt{n}},n] => 41.0594 = 42$

but the cheat sheet says it has to be 2.. which makes no sense since the power is 0.9 when i calculate it...

Comment: Most aspects of your formulas have no clear connection with the data in the question.  What does the "$\sqrt{9}$" represent?  What does the "$4$" represent? What happened to information about $\sigma=0.2$ and the mean of $4.05$ hours?

Comment: omg... I've mixed two exercises..
The answer makes sense now, could someone clarify that the method i've used is correct?

Comment: You should always keep the [underlying principles of statistical power](http://www.insight-things.com/power-statistical-tests) in mind.